# R: Object not found with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add legend names to a ggplot but I always get an "object not found error".

```
  mycol = pft$colour
  myname = pft$name
  #mycol "#E5E503" "#9FFF8C" "#44CC29" "#137300" "#B2B224" "#0066CC" "#99CCFF" "#00407F" "#FF999B" "#E5171A" "#990003" "#A38FCC" "#7F40FF" "#A1E5CF" "#6B998A" "#F2F291" "#BF60A7" "#404040"
  #myname "C4 grass" "Early tropical" "Mid tropical" "Late tropical" "Temperate C3 Grass" "North Pine" "South Pine" "Late conifer" "Early hardwood" "Mid hardwood" "Late hardwood" "C3 crop" "C3 pasture" "C4 crop" "C4 pasture" "C3 grass" "Lianas" "Total"             
  test_data_long = melt(szpft[[vnam]][,ndbh+1,],
                        varnames = c("year","mpft"), na.rm = T)
  ggplot(data=test_data_long,aes(x=year,y=value, colour = mycol[mpft])) +
    geom_line(aes(group = mpft)) +
    scale_colour_identity(guide = "legend") +
    scale_fill_continuous(name="PFT", labels = myname[mpft])
```

`test_data_long` is a `data.frame` that looks like this.

```
    year mpft     value
20  2004    2  2.294562
21  2005    2  2.415901
22  2006    2  2.532214
23  2007    2  2.649968
24  2008    2  2.760934
25  2009    2  2.849097
26  2010    2  2.967846
27  2011    2  3.102287
28  2012    2  3.244338
29  2013    2  3.386014
30  2014    2  3.528662
31  2015    2  3.675095
32  2016    2  3.828054
33  2017    2  3.976928
34  2018    2  4.133859
35  2019    2  4.305039
36  2020    2  4.488999
37  2021    2  4.673952
38  2022    2  4.861845
39  2004    3  4.518262
40  2005    3  4.668800
41  2006    3  4.821924
42  2007    3  4.973597
```

I would like to use the `mpft` column as an index to define grouping, color, title ecc.

`mycol` and `myname` are vectors that contain colours (hex) and names corresponding to the different `mpft` lines to plot. The exact error I get is

`Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'mpft' not found`

Removing the last line of the script produce the next figure, so the problem lies in the last line. Why is `mpft` recognized before and not after?

[image]

**EDIT**

To be clearer,

```
  mycol = pft$colour
  myname = pft$name
  test_data_long = melt(szpft[[vnam]][,ndbh+1,],
                        varnames = c("year","mpft"), na.rm = T)
  ggplot(data=test_data_long,aes(x=year,y=value, colour = mycol[mpft])) +
    geom_line(aes(group = mpft)) +
    scale_colour_identity(guide = "legend")
```

produces the graph in figure and gives no error.

**EDIT**

I'll provide a simplified, reproducible example of what I want to achieve here.

```
mycol = c("#A38FCC","#7F40FF")
mynam = c("random_line1", "random_line2")
set.seed(123)
df=data.frame(month = month.abb, 
          mpft  = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6)), 
          ran = runif(12,0.,10.))
```

That produces a dataframe with `month`, `mpft`, and `ran` value. I want the `ggplot` to have `month` on the x-axis and `ran` on the y-axis. Furthermore I want the points to be plotted with `mycol[1]` colour ("#A38FCC" color) and the legend to display `mynam[1]` as title (random_line1 as title) if `mpft = 1`.

Comment: You don't define `mypft` in your example code.

Comment: `szpft` isn't there as well, but your main problem is not doing what `ggplot2` likes best which is to pass it a `data.frame` with everything it needs in it vs referencing external vectors like you are. That is doable, but it's fraught with peril for inexperienced ggplot2 users. It would help SO folks answer if the question was reproducible.

Comment: @Roland Regarding `mypft` it's true that it's not explicitly defined but one of the cols of my `data.frame` is assigned that name. Is that not enough?

Comment: No, you probably mean`myname["mypft"]`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yes I read that somewhere, however in my case it would be quite difficult to implement. To have an external reference for the color seems to me quite logical, otherwise one would have to create a new column only for the purpose; or am I missing something?

Comment: @Roland No, the code I have posted is the result of

`print(test_data_long)`
 you can see that the second column is called `mpft`

Comment: Why are you arguing with me? You are trying to call an object `mypft` and R tells you it can't find it, which can have two reasons: (i) the object does not exist, i.e., has not been definded, or (ii) it's not on the search path, i.e. a scoping issue. Based on the code you have shared, option (i) seems to apply.

Comment: And yes you are missing something. Typically you would simply use `scale_color_manual` which allows to map colors to unique values.

Comment: Just type `myname[mypft]` in your console and you'll most likely see the same error.

Comment: As I wrote upon removing the last line (so leaving the `ggplot` command with `mpft` and `mycol[mpft]` still) gives no error. This to me proves that `mpft` is defined as a member of the `data.frame`.

Comment: @Axeman `mycol[mpft]` and `myname[mpft]` are both not found. That's because `mpft` is a member of my `data.frame` and not a variable. However the first one is correctly interpreted in the `ggplot` command and the second throws an error.

Comment: You are confusing standard and non-standard evaluation (SE and NSE). Within `scale_fill_continuous` (which should be `scale_color_continuous`) you need to specify thing using SE (i.e. the normal R way). So to refer to the column `mpft` in `myname`, you'll need to write either `myname$mpft` or `myname["mpft"]`.

Comment: Within `aes` you can use bare varialbe names (i.e. NSE), like how you define x and y, but constructs such as `mycol[mpft]` are definitely not a safe way of doing that.

Comment: So if one of my columns contains a variable which determines the colour to use in the plot, then how do I use this variable to select the coulour from an external list? That is suppose I want every `mpft = 2` row to be plotted with `#137300` colour, how do I do that?

Comment: @manfredo the column gets created _anyway_ inside ggplot2. You're just postponing the inevitable. If you really want a custom computed color scale, write a `scale_` function.

Comment: All this is because I am trying to port code from `plot` to `ggplot`. I am having the impression that the latter is much less flexible than the buil-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to the other answer but without needless dplyr mumbo-jumbo and pointing out some important details. The point is that if you want manual colors, you should use a manual color scale.

```
mycol = c("#A38FCC","#7F40FF")
mynam = c("random_line1", "random_line2")
set.seed(123)
df=data.frame(
              #month needs to be an ordered factor to get correct order in the plot
              #an unordered factor would be ordered alphabetically by ggplot2
              month = ordered(month.abb, levels = month.abb), 
              mpft  = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6)), 
              ran = runif(12,0.,10.))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=month,y=ran, 
               colour = factor(mpft) #you want a discrete color scale
               )) +
  geom_line(aes(group = mpft), size = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "mynam",
                      #always pass named character vectors here to ensure correct mapping
                      values = setNames(mycol, unique(df$mpft)), 
                      labels = setNames(mynam, unique(df$mpft)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works well for both the simplified example and the general case. Thanks for your help. Regards

Comment: Sorry, I talked a bit too fast. There's still a little problem but I think it's almost done. The problem lies in the fact that if you substitute `mpft  = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6))` with `mpft  = c(rep(2,6),rep(1,6))` the graph stays the same (while names and color should be inverted). This is because `setNames(mycol, unique(df$mpft))` and `setNames(mynam, unique(df$mpft))` make a sequential assignment rather than using `mpft` as the index for the `mycol` and `mynam` vectors. Let me know if this make sense.

Comment: Substituting `values = setNames(mycol[mpft], unique(test_data_long$mpft))` with `values = setNames(mycol[unique(test_data_long$mpft)], unique(test_data_long$mpft))` did the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: The "problem" is just sorting (and not related to ggplot2). How you provide the mapping is up to you. In this example, you could also do `setNames(mycol, sort(unique(df$mpft)))`. Btw., normally you would just do `df$mpft <- factor(df$mpft, levels = 1:2, labels = mynam)`. Then you could use the factor levels for color mapping.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Using the reproducible example given in an edit to the question, the following code is provided.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  ggplot(.,aes(x=month,y=ran, colour= as.factor(mpft))) +
    geom_line(aes(group = mpft)) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = guide_legend(title = "Legend"),
                     values = mycol,
                     labels = mynam)
```

This code will only give the right colours if all the lines are in the figure, if they aren't then the colours will change to prevent this use the following code.

```
  #This example uses three types, of which we only want 2
mycol = c("#A38FCC","#8f9e00","#7F40FF")
myname = c("random_line1","random_line2","random_line3")
set.seed(123)
df=data.frame(month = rep(month.abb,3), 
              mpft  = c(rep(1,12),rep(2,12),rep(3,12)), 
              ran = runif(36,0.,10.))

#this creates a dataframe that maps mpft to it's name and hex code
details <- data.frame(mpft = 1:length(mycol), 
                      mycol=(mycol), 
                      myname= myname, 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#merge the two data frames
df2 <- df %>% left_join(., details, by="mpft") 

#We experiment to see if the colour scheme is maintained by removing one of the types
df3 <- df2 %>% filter(mpft !=2)

#Arrange the newly formed dataframe in order of mpft, although it makes no difference in this example it is crucial if the observatiions of mpft are not in numerical order.
df3 <- df3  %>% arrange(mpft)

 #Colours wrong!
 df2%>%  ggplot(.,aes(x=month,y=ran, colour= myname)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = mpft)) + 
  scale_color_manual(guide = guide_legend(title = "Legend"),
                     values = unique(df2$mycol) )
#Colours Correct!
df3%>%  ggplot(.,aes(x=month,y=ran, colour= myname)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = mpft)) + 
  scale_color_manual(guide = guide_legend(title = "Legend"),
                     values = unique(df3$mycol) )
```

The above code chunk will maintain your colour scheme even if for some reason not all types are in the plot

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have made a second edit to reduce the problem to its minimal terms. Can you give it look, it might be easier to discuss on that

Comment: Could you say what was wrong with the first attempt I gave? Not sure if I understand the question correctly,

Comment: I am not sure about the second, I get some errors (%>% operator and others). The first actually works for the basic example but in fact just for that specific case. When you say `values = mycol` and `labels = mynam` you don't specify the index of that vector (which should be `mpft` in this case).